# How to schedule a backup for only the new added files?

Tags: backup, robocopy, xcopy

I'm a Windows user and wondering: how can I do a backup for the files on a specific folder if the files are not older than x days? Or to backup only the newly added/modified files without doing a full backup before it?

Answer (score 0):

I created a powershell code to do that which can be schadualed, It backup the files that is less than 60 days old and delete the backed-up files and folders if they are more than 60 days old

```
$src = "D:\Projects"
$dest = "G:\Backup\Projects"
$period = 60
$log_file = "G:\Backup\Logs\backup_" + (Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S") + ".txt"
robocopy $src $dest /MAXAGE:$period /S /TEE /NP /log:$log_file
forfiles -p $dest -s -m *.* /d -$period /C "cmd /c del @path"
```